# MLE estimation of scaled regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

Let's say I have a univariate (no intercept, for simplicity) regression with normally distributed errors,
$$y_i = \beta x_i + e_i, \text{ where }e_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2),$$
And I would like to find MLE estimators of $\beta$ and $\sigma$. Writing down the likelihood, we get
$$L(y|x, \beta, \sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp(-\frac{(y_i-\beta x_i)^2}{2\sigma^2})$$
$$\log L(y|x, \beta, \sigma) = - \frac{N}{2}\log 2\pi - N\log \sigma -\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{(y_i-\beta x_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$
Taking derivatives w.r.t. $\beta$ and $\sigma$, we can quickly find
$$\hat\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2}$$
$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\hat\beta x_i)^2$$

Now, let's say we scale down the regression by $\sqrt\sigma$, and get
$$y'_i = \beta x'_i + e'_i, \text{ where }$$
$$e'_i \sim N(0,\sigma),$$
$$ y'_i=y_i/\sqrt\sigma$$
$$ x'_i=x_i/\sqrt\sigma$$

If we rewrite the log-likelihood, we get
$$\log L(y'|x', \beta, \sigma) = - \frac{N}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{N}{2}\log \sigma -\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{(y'_i-\beta x'_i)^2}{2\sigma}$$

Substituting $y'_i$ and $x'_i$ with original $y_i$ and $x_i$, we get
$$\log L(y'|x', \beta, \sigma) = - \frac{N}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{N}{2}\log \sigma -\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{(y_i-\beta x_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$
Maximizing this w.r.t. $\beta$ and $\sigma$, we get

$$\hat\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2}$$
$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\hat\beta x_i)^2$$

There must be something I am missing, but why do we get twice as large $\hat\sigma^2$ in this case?